# How to create a queue on multiple clicking event

Tags: javascript, angular, events, onclick, rxjs

I have one question regarding this very specific situation I'm facing right now in Angular 4 / Typescript. I have 2 buttons (eg: Increase: "+", and Decrease: "-"), booth have onClick events to change current number's value.

On every click I do an API call to update new number value on Backend. If user clicks multiple times very fast (eg. 14 times to increase from 0 to 14 in less than 1 second) I will send 14 calls to the API.

I want to store the number increased and send the call just after 300ms from last call. Table representation:

```
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Clicks   | 1 . 2 . 3 . 4 . 5 . 6 . 7 . 8 . 9 . 10 . 11 . 12 . 13 . 14 |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Time     | 0ms ......... 300ms .............. 600ms ............ final|
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Api call | ............ send(5) ........... send(10) ........ send(14)|
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

I was searching on google about this but nothing found.

Comment: Look at rxjs debounce time debounceTime.

Comment: I have tried it, but it'll only delay all requests, and I will 14 api requests with delay instead of 3 at certain times.

Comment: Add your current code, without this debounce feature.

Comment: Wel,, post the code where you tried `debounceTime`. Why haven't you posted that code?

Comment: It's working but will wait 300ms after last click. in my case will send one request on 14 clicks, not one on 5th click and another one on 10th click. If you post you comment as an answer I will accept it, because i will keep this approach as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to combine debounceTime and distinctUntilChanged: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged.html

Example below will only emit the value if it is different than the last, polling every 300ms. You can call the next() function on your buttons and make the API call inside the subscription.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {


    value$ = new Subject<string>();

    constructor() {}   

    ngOnInit() {        
        this.value$
            .pipe(debounceTime(300))
            .pipe(distinctUntilChanged())
            .subscribe(result => {
                // call api
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is live demo at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/9zy4ovpx1p) and the minimal code representation is below.

Overall the `throttleTime` emits the latest value when specified duration has passed. [rxjs docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/throttletime.html)

I hope this will help you out.

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

import { throttleTime } from "rxjs/operators";

import { Subject } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  dumySubject = new Subject();
  clicker = 0;
  calls = [];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dumySubject.pipe(throttleTime(300)).subscribe(() => {
      this.calls.push(this.clicker);
    });
  }

  clickFunc() {
    this.clicker++;
    this.dumySubject.next(this.clicker);
  }
}
```